# Taking derivative of general order

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, version-10

How can I directly evaluate the following derivative?
     $$
 \frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}\bigg[\sum_{k=1}^{m} (m-k)! 
 (ax+b)^k\bigg] = \sum_{k=1}^{m} (m-k)! 
 \bigg[\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}a^n (ax+b)^{k-n}\bigg]
 $$

Mathematica code is

```
D[Sum[(m - k)! (ax + b)^k, {k, 1, m}], {x, n}] // FullSimplify
```

or even this will do:

```
D[(ax + b)^k, {x, n}] // FullSimplify
```

**[EDIT 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282046)**

```
nthDeriv[f_,x_,n_]:=n!*SeriesCoefficient[f[x],{x,x,n}]
f2[x_] := (a + b x )^k
nthDeriv[f2, x, m]
```

I obtain a weird output, however, for

```
f1[x_] := (1 +  x )^n
```

the above method works fine.

Comment: Have a look at `SeriesCoefficient`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks SeriesCoefficient seems to be yielding weird output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
D[(a x + b)^k, {x, n}]
```

is straightforward:

$$a^n k^{(n)} (a x+b)^{k-n}$$

Note:  don't use `ax` when you should use `a x`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But mathematica 10.04 does not yield the desired output. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 11.3.0.0 on a Mac.